# Jquery Confirm with Laravel Form does not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, confirm

I have this Jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.blog-form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var blog_form = $(this);

        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function (result) {
            if (result) {
                blog_form.submit();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And in my Laravel Form:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['Test\\TestController@destroy', $thread->id], 'method' => 'delete',  'class' => 'blog-form']) !!}
{!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

If I'm pressing the submit button, the confirm-message will appear. If I'm pressing on 'cancle', the confirmation of course disappear. so.. If I'm pressing the 'Ok' button, then the confirm message will fade out but at the same time a knew confirmation-message pops out. over and over again. So I can't press Ok, without getting another confirm-message. I wasn't able to solve this problem yet. Thanks for any help :)

Comment: It's because your "confirm message" is looping when you click 'OK'. Instead of `$('.blog-form').submit` try to use `$('.blog-form').click` and you should be fine.

Comment: works perfect! thanks :)

Comment: do you know how I can do something like a well formated : delete success output after confirm the confirmation?

Comment: That should be asked as a separate question. Also, seeing as the form submitted, you should probably use a Laravel flash notice.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling the same `submit()` function, which you intercept in jQuery. *One* way to prevent this, is by using a flag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var confirmed = false;
    $('.blog-form').submit(function (e) {
        if(confirmed){
            return;
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        var blog_form = $(this);

        bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function (result) {
            if (result) {
                confirmed = true;
                blog_form.submit();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: just replacing submit with click was enough :) thanks anyway :)

Comment: but do you know something like a confirmation message after the process is over? like: 'delete success'